# Why won't apps-script "onEdit" simple trigger work?

Tags: google-apps-script, triggers

I added this function, but editing any cell won't leave the desired note.
Why?

```
function onEdit(e) {
  // Set a comment on the edited cell to indicate when it was changed.
  const range = e.range;
  range.setNote('Last modified: ' + new Date());
}
```

Comment: This code works fine the way it is. After editing a value the note will update with the timestamp when it was last changed. Just in case you were not aware, you can already see when a cell was last edited and what was changed so your script will only make it visible on hover instead. If you right click a cell, you will see an option "Show edit history" which will tell you who made the change, when and what was changed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the first one I added (") and it works according to your requirements, in the second one I made a variant.

```html
function onEdit(e) {
  // Get the edited cell
  const range = e.range;

  // Sets the comment to the current date
  range.setNote("Last modification: " + new Date());
}
```

```html
function onEdit(e) {
  var range = e.range;
  var timestamp = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), Session.getScriptTimeZone(), 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss');
  range.setComment('Last modified: ' + timestamp);
}
```